# (web crawler) how to get the text of news passages from news website

Tags: java, php, python, web, jsoup

i m going to get the text from a news website that 
i have to get around 1k website content

the link is on below :
http://www.dcfever.com/news/readnews.php?id=16727

this website post every latest news and the new url is formed in adding 1 in the id

> readnews.php?id=**16727**

so ,next url will be

> readnews.php?id=**16728**

the question is i would like to scrape the text from 16000 to 17000

how to implement in Java

Jsoup? or other web crawler?

thanks

Comment: Jsoup works fine. What have you achieved so far?

Comment: some network errors occur    ,it seems that jsoup is not a stable library ,it cant extract all text in every pages

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged it `python` too. Look at `beautifulsoup` here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: it is better to use java library .  becoz i will scrape , analyze the data and run the whole program in java .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup is a HTML parser which can help you scrape and parse HTML page. If you already know the pattern of site navigation, Jsoup is good. But if you want to crawl all the contents of the website, you better leverage some crawler framework such as [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) or [Crawler4j](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j).

First you need to identify what you need to scrape from the page. eg. subject, author, content. Using css selector to extract what you want, for example, subject:

```
@Grab('org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2')
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect("http://www.dcfever.com/news/readnews.php?id=16727").get();
String subject = doc.select("body > div.site_wrapper > div.canvas > div:nth-child(5) > div > div.col-md-left.col-lg-left.read_article > h1").text();
```

You can run above code in groovy console and will get the result as below:

```
世界首部中片幅無反相機 Hasselblad X1D 登場
```

Comment: i extract the content according to its css layer by jsoup . I have to scrape over 1000 consecutive webpages ,say readnews.php?id=16727 to readnews.php?id=17727 . And i use for loop to extract data from every consecutive website  .The result is partially success .However , when i extract the text  toward certain number of websites ,say 50. The program collapses because of error . What is the problem? Does it mean jsoup is not an appropriate crawler for crawling constantly ?

Comment: please provide clear message, etc, Exception, error message. In fact, Jsoup is very good on handling web page and performance is quite good. more details pls

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [StormCrawler](http://stormcrawler.net). Implementing what you are describing should be very straightforward and most components are implemented in Java. You could generate the list of URLs incrementally and pass that for instance to a MemorySpout or put them in a file and use a FileSpout. It can run in distributed mode on an Apache Storm cluster but since you are processing only one site, scalability is not really an issue and you could run it in local mode.

Alternatively [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org) could also be an option, but you'll probably find StormCrawler a bit more straightforward to use and easier to customise.

Comment: can u explain why I crawl the text from websites mostly encounters the network errors? Is it my network problem ? Or should i slow down the speed of crawling every websites?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the logs. What settings did you use? Why don't you open a separate question and tag it with 'stormcrawler'? Could be your network indeed